# Swift: How to use more than one 'where' on conditional binding?

Tags: swift, conditional-statements

I did some google searched and the examples use " , " to use more than one where statement but it doesn't work for me. I have tried && as well.

```
if let movesDict = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] where movesDict.count > 0, movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up"{
}

if let movesDict = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] where movesDict.count > 0 && movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up"{
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: `&&` has worked for me. Is there something else that is wrong?

Comment: @TroyT i used if `let movesDict = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] where movesDict.count > 0 && movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up"{}` but they gave me this error **Cannot subscript a value of type '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]' with an index of type 'String'**

Answer (score 3):

You want `&&` - you must have some other problem with your code, as this works:

```
let foo: Int? = 10

if let bar = foo where bar > 8 && bar % 2 == 0 {
  print("It works")
}
```

Comment: i used if `let movesDict = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] where movesDict.count > 0 && movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up"{}` but they gave me this error **Cannot subscript a value of type '[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]' with an index of type 'String'**

Comment: Looks like you have an array of dictionaries, so you might want to get the 'learn_type' from the first one, or something.

Comment: I want to use movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up" for the whole array, how do i do it without looping through the whole array again.

Comment: You could do something like this `movesDict.filter({ $0["learn_type"] == "level up" }).count == movesDict.count` but I think it would be better to re-think your app a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You tried this:

```
if let movesDict = pokemonInfoDict["moves"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
    where movesDict.count > 0
        && movesDict["learn_type"] == "level up"
{
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that `movesDict` is a array of dictionaries, and you tried to use the string `"learn_type"` as the subscript of that array when you said `movesDict["learn_type"]`, but an array subscript must be an `Int`.

Comment: I see, so it should be like movesDict[0]["learn_type"] == "level up" but I need it to be the whole array not just index 0.  How do i do it in where statement without looping through the whole dict again?